# Shifting to polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

Let $\mathbf{r}:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2,\ a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$, be a $C^{\infty}([a,b])$ application (smooth). Is it true that we can always find two functions $r,\varphi :[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $r\in C^{0}([a,b])$ (continuous) and $\varphi\in C^{\infty}([a,b])$ such that:

$$\mathbf{r}(t)=r(t)(\cos\varphi(t),\sin\varphi (t)),\ \forall\ t\in [a,b]$$

? What can be said about the uniqueness of $r$ and $\varphi$, given $\varphi (t_0)=\varphi_0$?

Comment: Yes if $\mathbf r$ does not turn into the zero vector. But if it does, there is a problem with continuity of $\varphi$: consider $\mathbf r(t)=(t,0)$ with $t\in [-1,1]$.